# How do I combine multiple rows of data in R while still keeping row names?

Tags: r

I have 12 different dataframes that look like this. [image: Example]

All 12 share the same column headers with one row of data.

The first column is slightly different depending on their team name Ex: (HPMapUsageATL2, HPMapUsageCHI2, etc..). I am looking to combine all of them so I will have 12 different rows with all of their headers.

Right now I am using this code:

```
MapUsage <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(HPMapUsageATL2, HPMapUsageCHI2, HPMapUsageDAL2,
                                                            HPMapUsageFLA2, HPMapUsageLA2, HPMapUsageLondon2, 
                                                            HPMapUsageMinnesota2, HPMapUsageNewYork2, HPMapUsageOptic2,
                                                            HPMapUsageParis2, HPMapUsageSeattle2, HPMapUsageToronto2))
```

This does what I am looking it to do besides keeping the row names. It returns the dataframe like this:
[image]

How can I get the code to return the original row headers instead of it being numbered? Ex: HPMapUsageATL2

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to convert the `row.names` to a column before doing the `merge`.  Get the objects that start with 'HPMapUsage' all into a `list` with `mget`, loop over the `list` (`lapply`), create a new column with `transform`, and apply the `Reduce` with `merge` on the `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^HPMapUsage')) , function(dat)
        transform(dat, rn = row.names(dat))
 out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), lst1)
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = '^HPMapUsage')) %>%
      map(~ .x %>%
                 rownames_to_column('rn')) %>%
      reduce(full_join)
```